# I need to set width value in child element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

This my code..

```
<div style="width: 89px">
     <span class="copyText">This is some text to copy.</span>
     <span>Can't copy </span>
     <span class="copyText1">And this is yet more text.</span>
</div>
```

I need to get the div element width and add +6 px and to set this value to this span only `<span>Can't copy </span>`

if its possible pls give me the solution..

Comment: Document structure is not clear for me. Should I change the second span? Or span without classes? Or span with this text exactly? Also not clear why set the width of span if the parent div narrower. There will be no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you tagged a jquery .. you just need

```
var divWidth = $('div').outerWidth(); 
$('div > span:nth-child(2)').css('width' , divWidth + 6 +'px');
```

**Demo**

```js
var divWidth = $('div').outerWidth();
$('div > span:nth-child(2)').css('width' , divWidth + 6 +'px');
```

```css
div{
  background : #eee;
}

span{
  padding : 5px 0px;
}

span:not([class^=copyText]){
  background : #005eff;
  color : #fff;
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 89px">
     <span class="copyText">This is some text to copy.</span>
     <span>Can't copy </span>
     <span class="copyText1">And this is yet more text.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a combination of `children` and `width`:

```
var context = $("div");
(context.children("span")[2]).width(context.width() + 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="myDiv" style="width: 89px">
     <span class="copyText">This is some text to copy.</span>
     <span class="setSpan">Can't copy </span>
     <span class="copyText1">And this is yet more text.</span>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
var width = parseInt($(".myDiv").css("width").replace("px","")) + 6;
$(".setSpan").css("width",width);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible .

First fetch the width of the div and add 6px.

```
var width = parseInt($("div").css("width").replace("px","")) + 6;
```

Then using `nth` selector jQuery set the width.

```
$( "div span:nth-child(2)" ).css( "width", width );
```

Answer (score 0):

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/mjk2y432/3/) the script adds 6px to the width of the div and the second child span.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var wdth = $('div').width();
  wdth += 6;
  $('div').css({
    'width': wdth
  });
  $('div span:nth-child(2)').css({
    'width': wdth
  })
});
```

In such an example there are no issues selecting the div without a class or id, but if you would had more divs, it would be more complicated to select the one you want - therefore I reccomend putting a class or id to it, would you be able in your case.